# MYSQL JOIN (table colum value) ON

Tags: mysql, join

Is it possible something like this in MYSQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category = categories.id
INNER JOIN categories.description_name ON categories.description_name.id = products.id
```

Comment: I'm not sure what result you're looking for here. Can you clarify with some sample data and the expected result set?

Comment: No, table and column names are not expressions in SQL, they're always taken literally.

Comment: what is `categories.description_name`?

Comment: He's trying to join with a table whose name is in `categories.description_name`.

Comment: @Barmar, that's clear now.